# ASP.NET Core PhysicalFileProvider UNC error

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-server, network-share

Been trying to get this to work on my MAC for a while now, but still no luck.
In an ASP.NET Core app I am trying to get contents from my network share on a Windows Server. I read you can initiate Static Files through Startup.cs when you include:

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"\\192.168.178.101\2020$"),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/2020"),
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
});
```

Please note I am running this on a MacOS laptop. I have tried SMB URL also, but no luck. I can connect with the share fine through Finder.
I always get the error "The path must be absolute". The share on that server is a folder named 2020. I have tried also without $, but no luck. I also tried to put smb:// in front, but the it saw the UNC as a relative folder path.

I really hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The address format is not correct. It does not know the protocol. You can install nuget package `SharpCifs` and get file as:

```
var folder = new 
SmbFile("smb://UserName:Password@ServerIP/ShareName/FolderName/");
var modeDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

foreach (SmbFile item in folder.ListFiles())
{
    var modeDate = epocDate.AddMilliseconds(item.LastModified()).ToLocalTime();
    var name = item.GetName();
    var type = item.IsDirectory() ? "dir" : "file";
    var date = lastModDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    var msg = $"{name} ({type}) - LastMod: {date}";

}
```

Comment: Instead of using this method, I wanted to use the PhysicalFileProvider method. But are you assuming it is completely not supported in .NET Core on MacOS?

Comment: `PhysicalFileProvider` doesn't support the method of connecting smb. It can connect it through absolut path in file system.

Comment: I was looking up info and this link came up:https://www.jauernig-it.de/asp-net-coreiis-serving-content-from-a-file-share/. In there it is using a network file path. So why could that be used within Windows, but not within MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was using a library for this SMBLibrary, but later I even decided to build the solution on a Windows machine, which made it so much easier. Then the SMBLibrary is not even needed.